# Rsync not terminating when giving timeout

Tags: rsync

we are trying to setup timeout limit for rsync data transfer, below is the command executing:

```
rsync --bwlimit=10 --timeout=10 -e ssh -avzr --delete /u01/Oracle/SyncScriptFolder/source xxxxx@xxxxxx:/u01/Oracle/SyncScriptFolder/source --stats -i
```

based on above command the rsync should stop the execution/transfer if it do not completes in 10 seconds, but it still continues to execute and donot terminates.

Comment: We verified on other machines the timeout option is working. Is it possible to debug the rsync to understand the cause of this problem.

Comment: You could probably try contimeout option too.

Answer (score 0):

Terminate when no data transfer happens between source to destination. Check if there are any files are still updating in the source system.

Check the below bold text from the documentation,

--timeout=TIMEOUT
              This option allows you to set a maximum I/O timeout in seconds. **If no data is transferred for the specified time then rsync will  exit.**  The
              default is 0, which means no timeout.